# How can I remove "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge" and "continuous-integration/jenkins/branch" checks from showing on my GitHub pull requests?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a plugin installed for Jenkins that breaks down each stage of the run. For that reason I have no need for the extra two displayed checks, is there any way I can hide them?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue with installing the following plugin:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/disable-github-multibranch-status-plugin

For a Multibranch Pipeline, if you are using the Github Branch Source plugin, this plugin will give an additional option to disable GitHub reporting.

Comment: how do you enable this plugin for a particular build?

Comment: @EugenePlatonov you can just enable it for the whole MultiBranch Pipeline as a behaviour.

Comment: Does this plugin remove ONLY the two `continuous-integration/jenkins..` notifications as this is what you mentioned "...no need for the extra two displayed checks,.." ?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do this without installing an extra plugin. Go to the settings of target repo and under 'Code and automation' go to Branches and uncheck: 'continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge' and 'continuous-integration/jenkins/branch' from the 'status checks that are required' section.

Comment: It's removing as "required", but still visible in the "Status checks" section of the PR even it's not required anymore